# Is it possible to use a cucumber scenario as a function?

Tags: cucumber, capybara, factory-bot

Something like:

```
Scenario: Create a Test Category
  Given I am on the regression test test cases page
  When I follow "New Category"
  And I fill in "Name" with "Test Category"
  And I press "Add Category"
  Then I should see "Test Category" within ".test-categories-list"

Scenario: Add a Test Case
  Given I "Create a Test Category"
```

I would like a "step-by-step" procedure of creating a test category then creating a test case. Is this possible without doing a "Given I created a Test Category" then doing a Factory on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a situation where you should treat your test code just like your production code and encapsulate it in a class.
You can then easily reuse it wherever you need it.

For the sake of illustration:

```
class TestCategory
  def create(values)
    follow_new_category
    fill_in_name
    press_add
  end

  def follow_new_category
  end

  def fill_in_name
  end

  def press_add
  end
end
```

You can then call these methods from your steps:

```
When /I fill in "Name" with "(.*)"/ do |category_name| 
  TestCategory.new.fill_in_name(category_name)
end
```

(You may want to manage the lifecycle of the TestCategory class in some other way, rather than instantiating a new one each time...)

However, your steps are quite imperative which is not considered good practice. It would be nicer if it said something like this:

```
Scenario: Create a Test Category
  Given I am on the regression test test cases page
  When I add a test category
  Then I should see "Test Category" within ".test-categories-list"
```

Then you don't need to break it down your support code into so many minuscule methods.

Comment: so how do yo ucall that create method in your TestCategory class in cucumber?

Comment: can I do something like "Given Scenario: Create a Test Category" has run"?

Comment: no you can't. scenarios are independent. if you want reuse you should build into your code and/or your step definitions.

Comment: What you could do is say "Given a Test Category has been created" and reuse the code in the same way I described in the answer